# Newb question: I'm just having trouble using decimal.js in my script

Tags: javascript, decimal.js

I'm very new to JavaScript, and am trying to use decimal.js, for a project that requires its fractional exponents.

I've been trying every variation that I see in examples, but my variable declarations are failing, causing the script to abort.  The result is a blank document.

I've stripped the script down, to include just what I think will be needed for this question.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>My First Script</TITLE>
<script src="http://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js"></script>
<!--
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs/dist/math.js"></script>
-->

<HR>
<H1>Title</H1>
<HR>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> <!--
function myFunction(parm) {
    var Decimal         = require('decimal.js')
    Decimal.set({precision: 200});
    var dn              = new Decimal(parm)

    document.write(dn)
}

myFunction(123.456789)

// --> </SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: please formulate your question better. it's unclear what you are trying to achieve and what errors you are facing.

Comment: ok thanks - I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

I've only used `decimal.js` before as an npm package, not as a script loaded directly into a browswer, but `require('decimal.js')` is not how you'd load this script in a browser, and you *definitely* wouldn't want to load it *over and over again each time your function is called*.

Try just taking this line out: `var Decimal = require('decimal.js')`, and see how far you get. `Decimal` should already be defined as a global variable by loading the script.

Also, if you want to get the full precision 'decimal.js' offers, initialize value with string values, not numeric values, like this:

`myFunction('123.456789')`

Otherwise you'll never get any more precision than a regular JavaScript `number` provides.

Comment: Sorry, trying to format this comment. :)
@kshetline
I modified the function, and the result is that the first document write operation works, but the script aborts, before the rest.

'code'
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> <!--
function myFunction(parm) {
 document.write("step 0")
 Decimal.set({ precision: 20 });
 document.write("step 1")
 var dn    = new Decimal()
 document.write("step 2")
  dn.evaluate(parm)
 document.write("step 3")
 document.write(dn)
}

myFunction("123.456789")

// --> </SCRIPT>

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that's left to execute after the first `document.write`. What more do you expect to happen?

Comment: document.write("step 0")  writes step 0
then the script fails, on the next line of code
Decimal.set...
so document.write("step 1") and all of the lines after, never execute.

Comment: You seem to be referring to code that I don't see posted in your example, I see no `document.write("step 0")` above.

Comment: The problem was the src link.  And my downloaded file wasn't linking either, because of a Chromebook path issue.  The answer is simply to put the htm file in the same folder as decimal.js, and use the short link for src.